# telerik scheduler, custom provider and resources

Tags: telerik-scheduler

Hey all,
Im using the telerik radscheduler with a custom provider. In my custom provider, I have a number of custom resources that I want to expose on the advanced edit form. My question is how do I bind the controls on the form to the resources??

Any assistance is appreciated.
Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an AdvancedInsertTemplate or AdvancedEditTemplate. If you have for example a custom resource called "User" and you want to add a label in the advanced form for this user use code similar to this in the markup:

```
<asp:Label ID="UserLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.Appointment.Resources.GetResourceByType("User") == null ? "None" : Container.Appointment.Resources.GetResourceByType("User").Text %>' />
```

For more info on the Advanced templates - take a look at [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/templates/defaultcs.aspx).